# Spring RabbitMQ listener returns a string with comma seperated ASCII decimals

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a basic RabbitMQ listener in java using the spring framework rabbitmq listener annotation.

```
@RabbitListener(containerFactory="rabbitListenerContainerFactory", queues="myQueue")
public void process(@Header(value="type", required=true) String messageType, @Payload() String data){
   System.out.println(data);
}
```

If the message contains the payload

```
"test"
```

the returned data comes back as

```
"116,101,115,116"
```

It's still a string, but a string of ascii characters.

I'm posting the messages from the Rabbit web interface and if I read them from the web interface the payload is still a normal string.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved.  It wasn't anything to do with java.  The content_type wasn't being set within the message properties, it was in the header...

Comment: I will do, but I have to wait 2 days.

Comment: How you do it? Can you write example?